# How to solve File-based locking initialisation failed.

Tags: centos, lvm

Am on a CentOS-Minimal Virtual Machine, i had accidentally deleted a hard disk that contained a Volume Group (LVM). After rebooting i got an error saying " File-based locking initialisation failed". Any solution ?